# Set module in Edit Configurations option in intelliJ / Android Studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle

I've opened my Android project. But before run it, I have to Edit Configuration and choose the module. But anyone module appears in the Edit Configuration window. It is a project using Gradle.

**EDIT:**

When I open the Edit Configuration window, in the bottom it is showed the following message: "Error: Module not specified"

What I have to do?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I got the same problem after renaming the project. In the Edit Configuration window, there should be the option `Use classpath of module`. After I set the right module, it worked.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. The most confusing thing about this error is that when trying to run the configuration, IDEA opens the property sheet and places the focus on the _VM options_ text box. So I get an error message I don't understand and are left with an empty text box I have no idea how to fill in. In hindsight I guess you need to either select a module or specify a classpath, but IDEA doesn't tell you that :|

Comment: @mtyurt answer finally accepted (better late than never). The funny thing here is: I've encountered the same problem today, this time I was editing a configuration for JUnit. Then had a similar problem, but the error message was a little bit different: (Error: Module to choose classpath from is not specified), then I googled and found this question. When I saw the answer, I realized it was asked by me. haha
Thanks for your answer. Sorry for the later acceptance.

Comment: this option is note shown. Even this tab is not visible. I have "General" Tab.

Comment: how do you know what module to use exactly?

Answer (score 5):

I had a bad module, so I removed the old module and imported a new module from my project folder. (it doesn't delete any files)
File > Project Structure > Modules > Add > Import Module > Location of your project

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem,

But when i **download gradle and set GRADLE_HOME in environment**,
it successful,

You should try this instead.